# None files are copied after org-mobile-push is executed

Tags: org-mode

i am trying to get the mobileorg work, but fail always

after i run org-mobile-push when i am editing an org-file with the name plan.org i.e., in the directory Dropbox/MobileOrg, only files like index.org, checksum are created, but plan.org is not copied, and in the automatically created index.org file, none link information about the plan.org is included.

I am setting the emacs and orgmode just the same with the homepage. did I forget some configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your .emacs file something like in [this](http://mobileorg.ncogni.to/screencasts/MobileOrg-Dropbox-OSX/) video. If you don't have any files in org-directory and/or in org-agenda-files, nothing is copied.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make org-mode automatically push these files up to the MobileOrg, first these files should be linked with aganda.